# I'm unable to execute same function with multiple times in php

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli, login-script

Here is my code for login.php

```
require_once 'connect.inc.php';
require_once 'core.inc.php';

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $password_hash=md5($password);
    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
        $query="SELECT `id` FROM `login` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password_hash'";
        if($query_run = mysqli_query($stat,$query)){
            $query_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
            if($query_num_rows == 0){
                echo 'You have entered wrong username or password !';
            }
            else if($query_num_rows == 1){
                function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field) {
                    $res->data_seek($row); 
                    $datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
                    return $datarow[$field]; 
                }
                $user_id= mysqli_result($query_run, 0,'id');
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                header('Location: index.php');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'You have entered wrong username or password !';
        }
    }else {
        echo 'You must have to enter username and password';
    }
}
<form action="<?php echo $server; ?>" method="POST">
    Username:
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the userid" name="username">
    Password:
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password">    
    <input type="submit" value="Log in">
```

Here is the code for index.php

```
require_once 'core.inc.php';
require_once 'connect.inc.php';

if(get_status()){
$firstname=getinfo('firstname');
$lastname=getinfo('lastname');
echo 'You are logged in ,'.$firstname.' '.$lastname.'';
echo "<br><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a><br>";
}
else {
 include_once 'login.php';
}
```

Here is the code for core.inc.php

```
session_start(); 
ob_start();
$server =$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
@$ref_url=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
function get_status(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;  
}

function getinfo($field){
    $get_query="SELECT `$field` FROM `login` WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
    require 'connect.inc.php';
    if($query_run=mysqli_query($stat,$get_query)){
            function mysqli_result($res, $row, $f) {
            $res->data_seek($row); 
            $datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
            return $datarow[$f]; 
        }
        if($query_result=mysqli_result($query_run,0,$field)){
            return $query_result;
        }
    }
}
```

In above code(in index.php) when I use `$lastname=getinfo('lastname'); after using $firstname=getinfo('firstname');`. It gives me the following error.
`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare mysqli_result() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\good\core.inc.php:18) in C:\xampp\htdocs\good\core.inc.php on line 18`

Please someone help me out. I'm learning this language for first time.

Comment: You should learn parameterized queries, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 2):

Define the  function `mysqli_result` outside of function `getinfo`. Then call it from `getinfo`.

Since you have defined that function inside `getinfo`, The function definition of `mysqli_result` will be executed when first time `getinfo` is called. When you call `getinfo` for the second time, the function definition of `mysqli_result` will be executed again. But it is already defined and you will get that error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have javascript development background.

But in php we declare functions different way.

So for example your core.php should be like:

```
session_start(); 
ob_start();
$server =$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
@$ref_url=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
function get_status(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;  
}

function mysqli_result($res, $row, $f) {
    $res->data_seek($row); 
    $datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
    return is_array($datarow)?$datarow[$f]:false; 
}

function getinfo($field){
    $get_query="SELECT `$field` FROM `login` WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
    require 'connect.inc.php';
    if($query_run=mysqli_query($stat,$get_query)){
        if($query_result=mysqli_result($query_run,0,$field)){
            return $query_result;
        }
    }
}
```

Now we know that we daclared `mysqli_result` function in `core.php`

so if any php file will `require_once 'core.inc.php';` we don't need to redeclare this function. In your case in `index.php` you call `include_once 'login.php';` and in `login.php` you are trying to redeclare `mysqli_result` which is redundant. So your `login.php` fragment can be transformed to:

```
 else if($query_num_rows == 1){
     $user_id= mysqli_result($query_run, 0,'id');
     $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
     header('Location: index.php');
 }
```

I guess you are just beginner in php and other developers can give some other advices. But my answer is just about your question why you have an error 
 `Cannot redeclare mysqli_result()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please, for sake of all the goodness, **use PDO**

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM login WHERE username=? AND password=?";
$stmt  = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$username, $password]);
$user_id = $stmt->fetchColumn();
if($user_id) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'You have entered wrong username or password !';
}
```

**This. Is. All.** The code you need. These few lines instead of all that terrible mess you have, trying to re-animate a dead mysql_result function.